# new endeavor and my code isnt responding Renee

Tags: javascript

I am very new to web design and I am trying to get my javascript function and jquery to work.  i have been trying to figure this out for a few days. with the function, I cant see why it wont work:

this is in my js file

```
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML=
    "Thank you for signing up!";,
      document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML=
    "I look forward to speaking with you soon";
    }
```

this is in my html file

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Sign Up</button>
 <p id="sign"></p>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("div:hidden:first").fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).slideUp(1000);
```

Have I written something wrong?  Neither of these react.

Comment: Are you including the JS file (correctly) in your HTML file? Where is the corresponding markup for the jQuery method?

Comment: I thought it was.   I have changed id's, changed where the codes have been located in the page.  I have the links for the js file in the html file at the bottom of the body.

Comment: In that case, please share **all** of the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's broken with your code, 
wrapping the script tag in the bottom of your body should make all work well.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Sign Up</button>
<div>
    <p id="sign"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript + jQuery:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    let message = document.querySelector("#sign")
    message.innerHTML = "Thank you for signing up!";
    $("div:hidden").fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).slideUp(1000);
}
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

To make the message change, I think you have to use setTimeout so it changes/adds after few seconds...